# Certificate chaining while signing a jar file

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, tls1.2, java-web-start

How to introduce one level of certificate chain while signing a jar file? What I am trying to do is,

1. Sign a jar with generated private key.
2. Generate a CSR (Certificate Signing Request)
3. Generate a CA signed certificate where CA is self sign CA
4. import CA in jcontrol and browser and run the java web start application.

but unfortunately it didn't work and gave security warning.

Please suggest some good approach.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR: get the cert first**

Java codesigning uses the PKCS7/CMS signature format, wbich is based on X.509/PKIX public-key certificates. The sequence you posted uses the privatekey as it if magically appeared, but that is impossible. I'm going to bet your sequence actually was:

‍0. `keytool -genkeypair`

Although the name focusses attention on 'generate keypair', this single command actually does three things: generate a keypair; create a dummy, self-signed certificate for the public half of that keypair; and store *both* the private half of the keypair and the dummy certificate *together* in a keystore (usually a file). Note the `java.security.KeyStore` API does not support storing a privatekey -- or a publickey or raw keypair -- by itself, only a privatekey combined with a certificate chain. (The dummy cert, by itself, constitutes a trivial chain.) For concreteness I will call this dummy cert A.

‍1. Sign a jar with generated private key = `jarsigner`

You specify to `jarsigner` a privatekey *entry* in a keystore, but as above that entry actually contains the cert chain as well, in this case the dummy cert. The PKCS7/CMS signature *contains* a raw PKC signature (RSA, DSA, or ECDSA) computed using the privatekey, plus the cert which matches that privatekey and thus can be used to verify the signature, plus any chain cert(s) needed to validate the signing certificate. You can see this if you look at the contents of the `META-INF/<alias>.{RSA,DSA,EC}` entry in the resulting jar.

‍2. Generate a CSR (Certificate Signing Request) = `keytool -certreq`

‍3. Generate a CA signed certificate where CA is self sign CA

How you did this depends on your CA, but doesn't matter here. To be exact, a CA may have a self-signed *cert* for the public half of the CA keypair, but as above it actually signs certs it issues using the private half. For concreteness I will call the cert issued by the CA *for* the signing key B, and the CA's own self-signed cert C.

‍4. import CA in jcontrol and browser and run the java web start application.

I'm not sure if you mean B or C here. But *neither* will help in verifying the signature done in step 1, because that signature contains and specifies A as the 'signer' cert, i.e. the cert to be used to verify the signature. B is a cert fort for the same publickey, and *could* be used to verify the signature if the signature specified cert B, but it doesn't, and can't because B didn't even exist when the signature was created.

The correct sequence is:

1. `-genkeypair`
2. `-certreq`
3. use CSR to get cert B from CA. You don't actually need C here, although you might get it for convenicnce or reference.
4. **`-importcert` cert B** into the privatekey entry. (If you defaulted the `-genkeypair` alias to `mykey` you can default `-importcert` also, otherwise you must specify the same one.) This *replaces* the dummy cert A with the 'real' cert B in the privatekey entry. (Be careful not to import cert B to a *different* alias, or different keystore; this often doesn't give an error. but the result won't work correctly.)

   If the 'real' cert B needs one or more chain cert(s) to validate, as is (always?) true for certs from real public CAs like Digicert, GoDaddy, LetsEncrypt, etc, such chain cert(s) must be either included in step 4 (as a combined file, often a 'p7b' or 'p7c' file), or separately imported prior to step 4 into a separate trustedcert entry or entries. However, your in-house CA does not need any chain cert(s).
5. **now `jarsigner`** -- so the signature includes cert B (and its chain certs if any)

A. separately, cert C must be included in the truststore(s) used by the client system(s); this can be done anytime: after, during or before steps 1-5. For webstart, I *believe* putting it in Java Control Panel should be sufficient; AFAIK webstart isn't validated by the browser. *Applets* may have been, but applets haven't worked in browsers for several years or in Oracle Java higher than 8.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. More or less I have tried the similar steps which are as 1. imported self signed CA "testCA.pem" in keystore 2. generated privateKey 3. generated CSR 4. get the signed certificate from testCA.pem 5. imported signed certificate with the same alias name in keystore 6. used singed certificate in jcontrol as a signerCA which worked well with javaws command but didnt worked with browser.   JAVAWS Command: --- javaws https://localhost:8443/web/test.jnlp - worked well without any warning.   but same url via broswer gave security warning.

Comment: Okay, then try putting CA cert also in browser truststore. My understanding was that webstart should be launched by browser and then bypass it, but maybe I'm wrong or something has changed.

Comment: The main problem is, there are two certificates installed on the same server so when we hit url in browser then other certificate is being considered and because of that security warning displayed. could you please suggest how to resolve this issue?